My Heroku dynos are crashing immediately after starting. Can someone help me figure out what I did wrong?
I have a very simple web app I'm testing out which is a webhook and accepts post requests. I uploaded the .py file called app.py. This is it's contents:
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    data = request.get_json()
    print(data)
    return jsonify({'status': 'success'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()

My Procfile has this written in it:
web: python app.py
And here's my requirements.txt file contents (it automatically installs Python I don't need to specify it):
Flask==3.0.3
When I deploy to Heroku, the build works fine, it detects that the Procfile type is web, and then when I type Heroku ps it even shows that the dynos are starting.
But then shortly after it crashes.
Any idea what this could be?

So check your error logs? You can either check them from the Heroic dashboard, or using the heroku logs command from the CLI.
